# Hide/delete some of Outlook for Mac built-in folders

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

Microsoft Outlook for macOS 2016 (16.10)

There are several built-in folders that I don't use and there are no mails in them. If I delete them locally, they reappear immediately. Is there way to hiding them somehow?

I'm talking about following folders:

- Groups
- Conversation History
- Clutter

[image]